# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement in SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to fetch data by passing login details of my instance in my stored procedure. I am getting **ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement** error.

My procedure is :

```
DECLARE 
    v_row_count NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    SELECT Count(*) 
    INTO   v_row_count 
    FROM   erp_cloud_extract; 

    dbms_output.Put_line('Original count: ' 
                         ||v_row_count); 

    DELETE erp_cloud_extract; 

    COMMIT; 

    SELECT Count(*) 
    INTO   v_row_count 
    FROM   erp_cloud_extract; 

    dbms_output.Put_line('Deleted count: ' 
                         ||v_row_count); 

    Scs_integration ( 
    'https://example.com/analytics-ws/saw.dll?SoapImpl=nQSessionService', 
    'https://example.com/analytics-ws/saw.dll?SoapImpl=xmlViewService', 
    '/shared/Cloud_Exports/', 'user_id', 'password', 'Table_Name', 
'Column0:VARCHAR2(100)|Column1:VARCHAR2(100)|Column2:VARCHAR2(100)|Column3:VARCHAR2(100)|Column4:FLOAT|Column5:VARCHAR2(100)'
); 

SELECT Count(*) 
INTO   v_row_count 
FROM   erp_cloud_extract; 

dbms_output.Put_line('Refreshed count: ' 
                     ||v_row_count); 
END;
```

Here Scs_integration is the name of my generic procedure. Please help what is wrong in this procedure?

Comment: Impossible to find the error only by looking at your code. You need to post the full error stack. Execute in SQL*Plus and post the error stack. It will have the exact line number. If the error is in the procedure being called, then post the procedure code. Also, to get the deleted rows count, you should use `SQL%ROWCOUNT`.

Comment: Does `DELETE erp_cloud_extract;` need to be `DELETE from erp_cloud_extract;`?

Comment: @zedfoxus No, syntax is fine. `DELETE table` deletes all the rows.

Comment: @LalitKumarB ah, got it. Learned something new today. Thank you.

Comment: @LalitKumarB  I am executing this code in front end cloud environment (oracle Apex). I can't see the logs (only getting error codes). Is there anyway I can see logs?

Comment: @AshishJain AFAIK, for APEX there is `APEX_ERROR` for error handling. is there a way for you to execute it in SQL*Plus?

Comment: Code looks ok to me.

Comment: Unrelated but the first two `select count(*)` statements are useless. The first one can be replaced by checking `SQL%ROWCOUNT` _after_ the `delete` and the second one will always return `0` as you have just deleted all rows.

Comment: @LalitKumarB can you provide any documentation on the delete table_name statement? I know of no such thing and therefore would say that the Error in SQL Statement results from the delete table_name.

Comment: @jera Check this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/000a6/2).

Comment: @jera: Yes it works both DELETE <TABLE_NAME>; and DELETE FROM <TABALE_NAME>. Also you can include WHERE conditions in both the cases.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

How about that extra whitespace in `Scs_integration (`. 
Could that be it?